# JFrame background color not working

Tags: java, swing, colors, jframe

**My code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Flappy bird");
    frame.setSize(1200, 800);
    FlappyBird game = new FlappyBird();
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
    frame.setResizable(false);
    while (true) {
            game.moveBall();
            game.gameOver();
            game.moveRect();
            game.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(14);
        }

}
```

Why isn't the `frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);` working?

I've tried to rearrange the order, like setting the color after making the frame visible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is on why a component of core java was implemented in the way it was, and not some other way. It is what it is

Comment: @ControlAltDel I disagree, the reason is a different one. Please check my answer below.

Comment: @Thomas I stand corrected :)

Comment: @ControlAltDel No worries ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works alright, but you cannot see the background color because your `FlappyBird` instance is drawn on top of it. You can easily verify this by replacing your game class with an empty canvas like so:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Flappy bird");
    frame.setSize(1200, 800);
    //FlappyBird game = new FlappyBird();
    Canvas game = new Canvas();
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
    frame.setResizable(false);
    // while (true) {
    //         game.moveBall();
    //         game.gameOver();
    //         game.moveRect();
    //         game.repaint();
    //         Thread.sleep(14);
    // }
}
```

There are two things you can try:

1. Setting the background color not of the frame's content pane but of `game`:

```java
//frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
game.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
```

2. Making sure that the frame's background color shows through the game instance by making the latter transparent:

```java
game.setOpaque(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the lines related to game, I was able to run this with the expected yellow result. The issue must be within the while loop

```
while (true) {
        game.moveBall();
        game.gameOver();
        game.moveRect();
        game.repaint();
        Thread.sleep(14);
    }
```

or

```
frame.add(game);
```

Without the FlappyBird class it's impossible to say exactly what is causing the issue, but based on the method names I'd look at repaint().